# How to efficiently implement AJAX on a dynamic PHP website after it is completed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, content-management-system, ecmascript-5

I am implementing a blog from scratch (a CMS) with PHP and MySQL, and I'm nearly finished with it, using these languages. I have not used Javascript and AJAX to send key/value pairs. But I'm thinking of adding AJAX functions, asynchronously, to make it as dynamic as possible. My question is:

Is it possible to implement AJAX after finishing my entire blog system in PHP?

In other words, and to clarify my question, after finishing this website, can I add AJAX without any conflicts? Or is it necessary to consider, to incorporate AJAX "before" the development of the CMS and during development of the system?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Sure. You might need to do some refactoring, depending on how you want to implement it, but that's just a normal part of the development cycle...

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the answer is yes.

Wheter it's the best route, I guess that's personal but does not have my liking. I think planning all your steps/functionality in front is best (not always possible though).

One good thing is that you're certain your CMS/Blog will work just fine even though the user/browser has javascript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but i didnt agree with Peter. my answer is STOP your work, and start learn AJAX.

Yes, Pure PHP is can work perfectly with/without javascript enabled. But come on, almost of us keep enable javascript. Most of Every device have javascript enabled by default. Only experince user know how to and when he needed to disabled javascript. otherwise we cant enjoy most of popular website around the world. we cant use fb chat, we dont know when we have new email without refreshing it. And the fact is we still can provide worked website with/without javascript (although in my experience, most of ajax user will forgot/ignore to provide worked website without javascript enabled)

i learn PHP by self-taught and dont have any friend that knows programming in my office.

I learn HTML, CSS, PHP and mysql. Try to implement in my office. I build my web. the example is create TABLE with PAGINATION. I make HTML and PHP as 1 page.[version 1]

```
table.php
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET['page']) $table=getDataFromDB($_GET['page']); 
else $table=getDataFromDB(0);

<table>
foreach($table as $row)
{
echo blablabla
}
</table>
?>
```

But when i need some feature that need AJAX. i learn AJAX , then i realize :

1. AJAX is more fast (we dont need to load HTML, CSS, js again, just send and get the data which we needed)
2. some feature only can implement with AJAX, ex: chat, real-time chart
3. AJAX make user more comfortable, and make our website more interactive
4. most of popular website use AJAX. ex: gmail, twitter (most of them, but not all. because AJAX have weak point too)

then i implement AJAX on my web [version 2]. and i feel like recreate my web almost 70-80% of it. i must change most of everything in my previous code. Because ajax work differently

```
table.php (DISPLAY)
<?php 
<table>
AJAX CONTENT WILL BE HERE
</table>
<script>YOUR JAVASCRIPT AJAX THAT CALL process.php TO FILL THE TABLE</script>
?>

process.php
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['page']) $table=getDataFromDB($_GET['page']); 
else $table=getDataFromDB(0);
foreach($table as $row)
{
echo blablabla
}
?>
```

So if someone told me

A: "i finished my learn about HTML, CSS, PHP. Can you tell me the simple website that i can make?"

Me: dont build Website first. learn about AJAX first then TRY to build website. because you will destroy your older website when you know what is ajax in the end

> if you are struggle to find the answer. Try build table with
>   pagination using pure PHP, then build the second with AJAX. You will
>   know what is the differ

So my advice is:  If your project is only for study and practice. Just stop it. Learn ajax first then build your website. But if your project is your office task. Just build it until finish. then learn ajax. otherwise your boss will fire you, because destroy almost everything in there.

and the last thing which not in your question (only for information). i start to recreate my website again and again when i learn MVC [version 3]. i use codeigniter now

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer @plonknimbuzz. I appreciate it and i agree with you because it`s not ease to use ajax over PHP code, because, for example, the header ('Location') method that just when i called a responseText via AJAX the entire web page appears. i must say as well that my code is not made on object oriented Programing, so i can`t use the code again, but i`m experimenting another serious problems right now and i will write a new post publishing the most difficult issues in this work. Thank you all for your support.